# Asp.net MVC 4 application Server not terminates session if email in database is empty and all users redirecting to that user page with no email

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my Website I have signup page where I have option to signup with facebook I'm storing the data from facebook(email, firstname lastname, pictureurl and facebook id) on my database but sometimes there are users  that signed with facebook that have no email or its closed by facebook in that cases their session are not stopping so all my users can't logout they redirecting to this person page what to do in this case

Answer (score 1):

How about making the email field nullable in your database?

That way it will just set it to Null if it doesn't exist.

**Update**

Changing slightly due to your comments.

Could it be that when it reads the data it is expecting it not to be null?

Do a quick check when reading it in so it becomes like this:

```
 email = email ?? string.Empty;
```

Comment: my Email field is already nullable its a string field and null allowed

Comment: now I'm adding fake emails if there are no emails but it will be good to understand why crash happens

Comment: In that case are you checking for null when trying to read the data? It could be that its expecting something but because its null it doesnt like it.